# texts in array converts to objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using node to convert an array to object, I have an array looks like this

```
[
'items[0].book=Book1',
'items[0].color=Red',
'items[0].bookCode=#1',
'items[1].book=Book2',
'items[1].color=Yellow',
'items[1].bookCode=#2',
'items[2].book=Book3',
'items[2].color=Blue',
'items[2].bookCode=#3',
...
]
```

I am trying to convert it to be objets in one array

```
items:[
  {
    book: "Book1",
    color: "Red",
    bookCode: "#1"
  },
  {
    book: "Book2",
    color: "Yellow",
    bookCode: "#2"
  },
  ...
]
```

I found it is easy to conver it uses a 3rd party lib like `setKeypath/set`,

```
const obj = {};
const arr = [items......(like above)]
arr.forEach((val => {
  if (val.startsWith('items[')) {
    const splitWord = item.split('=');
    setKeypath(obj, splitWord[0], splitWord[1]);
  }
});
```

I am seeking a way if it can be done the same output with `es6`, so I don't really need a library. Thanks

Comment: Is the format for the array always consistent? that is, every `items` will have the three values and sorted? If so, a simple regex should do

Comment: Will the array always `items` or will that change as well? Eg.g `'stuff[0].book=Book1'`

Comment: yes, always `items` as start, thats why I used `startsWith`

Comment: not always 3 values, sometimes I found 4 values, but generally 3 values. @BurningAlcohol

Comment: How are you generating that array? If it is from form encoded post data there would be a simpler approach for all of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
[
  'items[0].book=Book1',
  'items[0].color=Red',
  'items[0].bookCode=#1',
  'items[1].book=Book2',
  'items[1].color=Yellow',
  'items[1].bookCode=#2',
  'items[2].book=Book3',
  'items[2].color=Blue',
  'items[2].bookCode=#3',
].reduce((acc, str) => {
  const index = Number(str.slice(str.indexOf('[') + 1, str.indexOf(']')));

  if (!acc[index]) {
    acc[index] = {};
  }

  const entry = [str.slice(str.indexOf('.') + 1, str.indexOf('=')), str.slice(str.indexOf('=') + 1)];

  acc[index][entry[0]] = entry[1];

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Here I pick apart the string you're given based on the consistent format, grab the index, key, and value, and then just use Array#reduce to do the work of putting the array together.

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2):

```
const items = [
  "items[0].book=Book1",
  "items[0].color=Red",
  "items[0].bookCode=#1",
  "items[1].book=Book2",
  "items[1].color=Yellow",
  "items[1].bookCode=#2",
  "items[2].book=Book3",
  "items[2].color=Blue",
  "items[2].bookCode=#3"
];

let res = [];
let currId = "";
let currItem = null;
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let parts = items[i].split(".");
  if (currId!==parts[0] && currItem) { //new item
    res.push(currItem)
    currId = parts[0];
  }
  if (!currItem)
    currItem = {};
  let keyValue = parts[1].split("=");
  currItem[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1]
}
console.log({items: res})
```

Answer (score 2):

You may first find all values by regex, and insert the attribute to each corresponding element one by one. This approach works for whatever ordering the array is, and whatever attributes there are, as long as each element follow the same pattern.

```js
let items = [
    "items[1].bookCode=#2",
    "items[0].book=Book1",
    "items[0].bookCode=#1",
    "items[1].book=Book2",
    "items[2].bookCode=#3",
    "items[1].color=Yellow",
    "items[2].book=Book3",
    "items[2].color=Blue",
    "items[0].color=Red",
    "items[4].test=test!"
];

let indexPattern = /\[(\d*)\]/;
let attrPattern = /\.(.*)=/;
let valuePattern = /=(.*)/;
let obj = Object.values(
  items.reduce((obj, element) => {
    let index = element.match(indexPattern)[1];
    let attr = element.match(attrPattern)[1];
    let value = element.match(valuePattern)[1];
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(index)) obj[index] = {};
    obj[index][attr] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {})
);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a smattering of regex would do the trick:

```js
const ar = [
        'items[0].book=Book1',
    'items[0].color=Red',
    'items[0].bookCode=#1',
    'items[1].book=Book2',
    'items[1].color=Yellow',
    'items[1].bookCode=#2',
    'items[2].book=Book3',
    'items[2].color=Blue',
    'items[2].bookCode=#3'
]

const result = [];

ar.forEach(item => {
    const index = parseInt(item.match(/\[([0-9]+)\]/)[1]);
    const params = item.split(".")[1].split("=");
    if(!result[index])
        result[index] = {}
    result[index][params[0]] = params[1];
})

console.log(result)
```

Note that `item.match(/\[([0-9]+)\]/)` matches the number inside your brackets. `match` returns an array where 1 is the index of the actual value between the brackets.